# How to set boundaries for image move in android

Tags: android, android-view

I created an image view and moved it with an `OnTouchListener`. How can I limit movement to the boundaries of the screen?

Comment: You should accept one of these answers.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar based on the code I found here:  [DragView Example](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/)

It is based on the google's launcher code.  To keep the view on the screen I modified the onTouchEvent method to keep the view on screen.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (!mDragging) {
        return false;
    }
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final int screenX = clamp((int)ev.getRawX(), 0, mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels);
    final int screenY = clamp((int)ev.getRawY(), 0, mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels);
    //**ADDED to keep view entirely on screen
    final int[] parentpos = {-1,-1};
    ((View) mDragSource).getLocationOnScreen(parentpos);
    int minScreenX = parentpos[0] + (int)mTouchOffsetX;
    int minScreenY = parentpos[1] + (int)mTouchOffsetY;
    int maxScreenX = minScreenX + ((View) mDragSource).getWidth() - mDragView.getWidth();
    int maxScreenY = minScreenY + ((View) mDragSource).getHeight() - mDragView.getHeight();
    //end ADDED
```

and here

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // Update the drag view.  Don't use the clamped pos here so the dragging looks
        // like it goes off screen a little, intead of bumping up against the edge.
        // **CHANGED to keep view entirely on screen
        mDragView.move(clamp(screenX,minScreenX,maxScreenX), 
                clamp(screenY,minScreenY,maxScreenY));
        // end CHANGED
```

and here

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (mDragging) {
            // **CHANGED to keep view entirely on screen
            drop(clamp(screenX,minScreenX,maxScreenX), 
                    clamp(screenY,minScreenY,maxScreenY));
            //end CHANGED
        }
        endDrag();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display an image in the page, use the code below:

```
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="2px"
        android:src="pathOfImage" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

or you can set the hight and width using the code below:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();

    ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compute you screen size and can fix image move within the screen some how like this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            width = display.getWidth();
            height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `OnTouchListener`, you want `OnDragListener`. Look for the different `DragEvent` action types to get information on where your View is located. From there, as long as you know the dimensions of your `View`, you can prohibit it from moving outside the screen.